# How do I set a default sort parameter in Ransack to avoid error: "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, parameters, initialization, ransack

This is a beginner's question, and hopefully will have a simple answer!

I have a Rails 7 app that includes a **parks** index page. I am using Ransack that lets the user sort by **distance**, **rating**, or **name**. If a sort value is set (e.g. I load the URL `http://localhost:3000/en?q%5Bs%5D=distance+desc`) then it works fine. But I'm getting the following error when you load the parks index with no sort applied:

> undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

How can I set a default initial sort `[:s]` value (e.g. "average_rating desc")? (Note: If I simply remove `.order(params[:q][:s])` then the distance sort doesn't work properly.)

```
class ParksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @parks = @q.result(distinct: true).includes(:visited_users, :favorited_users).order(params[:q][:s]).near(@user_coordinates, 100000000).paginate(page:params[:page], :per_page => 24)
  end
end
```

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_search

  def set_search
    @q = Park.ransack(params[:q])
  end
end
```

I tried adding this line (@q.sorts...) and it didn't work:

```
  def set_search
    @q = Park.ransack(params[:q])
    @q.sorts = ['average_rating desc', 'distance asc'] if @q.sorts.empty?
  end
```

Updated to add definition for @user_coordinates:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_user_coordinates

  def set_user_coordinates
    if Rails.env.production?
      @user_coordinates = request.location.coordinates
    else
      @user_coordinates = [32.0908425,34.8154259]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hm, nobody has chimed in yet, maybe this is not such a beginner's question?...

Comment: check if it works by removing .order(params[:q][:s]) from index action of controller. I guess the error will be fixed if you check existence of params Example: .order(params[:q][:s]) if params[:q].present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search link helper with **default_order** values as given in doc https://activerecord-hackery.github.io/ransack/getting-started/simple-mode/#search-link-helper

```
 @parks = @q.result(distinct: true)
.includes(:visited_users, :favorited_users)
.near(@user_coordinates, 100000000)
.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 24)
```

To specify a [default search sort field + order](https://activerecord-hackery.github.io/ransack/getting-started/sorting/#sorting-in-the-controller) in the controller index:

```
@q.sorts = 'name asc' if @q.sorts.empty?
```

Comment: Hm, with this I'm getting a different error: "undefined method `near' for false:FalseClass", I think it's trying to evaluate the near method on "params[:q].present?". Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: .near(@user_coordinates, 100000000) If param[:q].present?

Comment: Also share the code for @user_coordinates

Comment: I guess I'm trying to figure out how to do conditional method chaining. I've been googling and searching stackoverflow but haven't yet figured out how it works here.

Comment: Added @user_coordinates definition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251320/discussion-between-dave-and-rebecca).

Comment: Updated the code in answer by removing `.order`. Apply the sorting as given in doc https://activerecord-hackery.github.io/ransack/getting-started/sorting/ and it should just work fine.   Example: `@q.sorts = ['average_rating desc', 'distance asc'] if @q.sorts.empty?`.  if the sorting is not rendering the expected results then try removing the `.near(@user_coordinates, 100000000)` and check the results. Specifying location coordinates will affect the results.

Comment: I am using the @q.sorts line currently. The .near method is required in order to be able to sort on distance, because without using the .near method there is no distance column added (from what I understand in the documentation). Thanks for your help - for now I can sort by distance in one direction (the useful direction at least!) so there's that.